# How to build project with local spring f/w building with gradle

Tags: spring, gradle

I downloaded spring framework from github.

After changing spring framework code , I builded spring framework with gradle.

and I want to test these in my new project.

but jars are in each ${baseDir}/libs directory.

-> like this..

..\spring-beans\build\libs\spring-beans-4.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
..\spring-core\build\libs\spring-core-4.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar

I can't gather jar files in one dir.

How can add jar files in new project?

The new project is based on gradle or... on maven, doesn't matter

root project is different between spring f/w and new project..

Comment: which github repo did you clone?

Answer (score 0):

One option is two install the customized spring artifacts to your local maven repository using "gradle install" and resolve the artifacts from there using the mavenLocal() repository. You should give the customized spring a custom version to ensure you don't hit any conflicts.